# React useContext TS typing state setter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to setup a context provider for a parent component:

```
import React from "react";

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  ReactQuiz: undefined;
};

type Score = {
  correct: number,
  incorrect: number
}

export type ReactQuizContextType = {
  score: Score;
  setScore: (score: Score) => void;
}

export const ReactQuizContext = React.createContext<ReactQuizContextType>({
  score: {
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0
  },
  setScore: () => void
})

export const useReactQuizContext = () => React.useContext(ReactQuizContext);
```

But I'm not sure how to type the setScore function, I'll be passing the following state as a value to the provider:

```
  const [score, setScore] = React.useState({
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0,
  });
```

But I can't type the function in the context using the same type ts is giving me:

```
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{
    correct: number;
    incorrect: number;
}>>
```

I tried typing the function with:

```
() => void;
```

and

```
(score: Score) => void
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: It does work for me [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYKL2N). Am i missing something?

Comment: Ah apologies, I had a syntax error, thank you!

Comment: yeah, `void` is not a valid typescript type. Should write that as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware of that at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that you are trying to use for the `setScore` is correct. The problem is with the initial value of it. `void` is not a valid thing in Javascript.

You can replace it with:

```
setScore: () => {},
```